# Airflow DAG explodes with RecursionError when triggered via WebUI

Tags: airflow

- I'm testing changes after major refactoring / re-write of my current Airflow workflow
- I'm still on `LocalExecutor` since all my tasks execute some commands / on remote machines (no actual computation heavy-lifting done within same Airflow machine)
- DAGs are being generated via a python script that reads locally stored JSON files (one DAG per JSON object in file)

After several days of rewrite I was able to generate my DAGs in the said way (programmatically)

---

However upon trying to trigger the DAG via UI (while testing, I set `schedule_interval=None` so triggers are manual), the DAG explodes (nuclear bomb text image) with following stacktrace (see complete stacktrace [here](https://gist.github.com/y2k-shubham/b312360506ad8fa2a814998af1b2b40b)) likely thrown from [this place](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/57da45685457520d51a0967e2aeb5e5ff162dfa7/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L546)

```
  recurse_nodes(t, visited) for t in task.upstream_list
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 1483, in <listcomp>
    if node_count[0] < node_limit or t not in visited]
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 1478, in recurse_nodes
    visited.add(task)
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 2304, in __hash__
    hash(val)
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 2304, in __hash__
    hash(val)
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 2304, in __hash__
    hash(val)
  [Previous line repeated 477 more times]
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 2302, in __hash__
    val = getattr(self, c, None)
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 2396, in dag_id
    if self.has_dag():
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 2392, in has_dag
    return getattr(self, '_dag', None) is not None
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Additionally, when I reload the webUI (or open a different browser tab), I can see the DAG stuck in `RUNNING` state (all `TaskInstance`s have `state` / `PID` = `NULL`).

[image]
[image]

---

Interestingly enough, once this happens, until I mark the DAG as failed via UI, I start getting the following stacktrace at `/logs/scheduler/latest/<path/to/my/dag_script.py.log>` (apparently thrown from [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d4a8afb5aef5b00f7c52c7ff1cc4088c8a00f4a7/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py#L640))

[image]

```
[2019-12-24 06:27:32,851] {jobs.py:1446} INFO - Processing derived_tables_presto_cbot_events_1
[2019-12-24 06:27:32,855] {jobs.py:921} INFO - Examining DAG run <DagRun derived_tables_presto_cbot_events_1 @ 2019-12-23 13:08:36.747641+00:00: manual__2019-12-23T13:08:36.747641+00:00, externally triggered: True>
[2019-12-24 06:27:32,856] {jobs.py:410} ERROR - Got an exception! Propagating...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 402, in helper
    pickle_dags)
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1760, in process_file
    self._process_dags(dagbag, dags, ti_keys_to_schedule)
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1451, in _process_dags
    self._process_task_instances(dag, tis_out)
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 930, in _process_task_instances
    if len(active_dag_runs) >= dag.max_active_runs:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

---

Once I mark the Dag as failed via WebUI, the above stacktrace from scheduler logs disappears (the `TaskInstance`s of that DAG continue to exist in Airflow's meta-db unless I manually delete them using a `DELETE FROM..` SQL query)

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

I've tried several things without success

- Ascertained that my Airflow `LocalExecutor` deployment is still intact (older workflow's DAGs are still running fine)
- Killing and restarting Airflow's `scheduler` & `webserver` several times
- `airflow initdb`
- Checked `airflow.cfg` file for any discrepancies

---

I'm using

- `Python` `3.7.3` (installed via [`PyEnv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv))
- `Airflow 1.10.3` with `LocalExecutor`
- `Linux ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: looks like there are several different problems in my workflow. the `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'` in `scheduler` logs was occuring because my code (which read configs from JSON files) was inadvertently passing `max_active_runs=None` to the DAG object, which is [clearly not desirable](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/803a87f2b2b564b3e8784de305f5bb4e9578e578/airflow/models/dag.py#L212) (we should pass nothing rather than explicitly passing `None`). I'm yet to solve `RecursionError`

Comment: Do you mine showing the task order code? E.g. `task_a >> task_b`...

Comment: **@absolutelydevastated**, please find the `'task order code'` [here](https://gist.github.com/y2k-shubham/b312360506ad8fa2a814998af1b2b40b#file-task_order_code-py). Also I forgot to inform that once the [`max_active_runs` issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59462957/airflow-dag-explodes-with-recursionerror-when-triggered-via-webui#comment105111060_59462957) was resolved, the Dag started running, i.e. tasks are executing (but it still gives that nuclear-bomb screen with `RecursionError` the moment i trigger it => even though it starts running normally in background)

Comment: [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/d657074dc5b1265ddb45ec24384e686a898c47a418eb224bd49bca96%40%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E)'s the link to the corresponding thread on airflow-dev apache-mailing list

Comment: There are chances that something is wrong in the 2 custom Operators you have created. Can you try commenting those out (or replacing them with DummyOperator) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: From the log it seems like the error originated from the Airflow library. My hunch is that the way you build your DAG might be the reason why. You can try what @kaxil suggested first and if that doesn't work, move everything to be more explicit instead of OOP to find the bug.

Comment: As pointed out by **@kaxil** and seconded by **@absolutelydevastated**, indeed replacing custom operators with `DummyOperator`s fixed the DAG-explosion issue. Though I'm yet to debug my custom operators to point to the root cause of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rightly [pointed out by **@kaxil**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59462957/airflow-dag-explodes-with-recursionerror-when-triggered-via-webui#comment105117318_59462957), the bug was in one of the custom operators

---

I had carelessly used a method defined within operator's class as `on_failure_callback`, and therefore the `self` param of that `kill_task()` method was leading to `RecursionError` and exploding of `DAG`

```
class MyCustomOperator(BaseOperator):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.on_failure_callback = self.kill_task
    ..
    def kill_task(self) -> None:
        // do some cleanup work
```

---

Moving the `kill_task()` method outside the class resolved the issue

Comment: Thanks for this. Made exactly the same mistake. You saved me a lot of time.